# Show window dimensions in titlebar in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm

In the default Terminal app the current width and height of the window are always displayed in the title bar, whereas in iTerm2 they're only displayed for a few moments when resizing.

How can I change it so that they're always visible in iTerm2 too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't find the correct variable for the title. But if you go to `iTerm2-> Preferences -> Profiles -> Session -> Configure Session`, you can create a custom menu component with title as `\(rows) x \(columns)` and it will show the width. I know it's not the perfect solution but will do your job.

[image]

Make sure your `status bar enabled` is checked.

Comment: You were on the right track, going to `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Name` and changing the name to `\(columns) x \(rows)` does the job.

Comment: Actually now I have the opposite problem, when I resize the terminal dimensions are displayed twice. Do you know how to not to show the dimensions when resizing?

Comment: I could not find an easy way to do this except write a custom script to change the behavior of the windows resizing. I will try this later and update here if I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `zsh` you can also override your title bar's content by adding a `precmd()` function like the following to your `~/.zshrc`.

```
precmd()
{
  echo -ne "\e]1;$(dirs -p | head -1) - $COLUMNS\x78$LINES\a"
}
```

Resulting window title e.g.: `~/Projects - 80x24`

| Segment | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| `precmd()` | Always called just before a new prompt is shown. |
| `echo -n` | Omits the default newline (necessary). |
| `echo -e` | Ensures escape sequences are processed. |
| `\e]1;TEXT\a` | `[ESCAPE]` `]1;` `TEXT` `[AUDIBLE-BELL]` - the necessary escape sequence to change the window title. |
| `$(dirs -p | head -1)` | Current working directory using `~`; e.g. `~/Projects` |
| `$COLUMNS\x78$LINES` | `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are shell variables. `\x78` is the hexadecimal code for `x` - if we wrote `$COLUMNSx$LINES` then the shell would be looking for `COLUMNSx` as a variable. |

Caveat: altered dimensions only change in the window title after you run a command.

Answer (score 0):

Building on noibe's previous comment, here's a way to accomplish it within the current version of iTerm2 (3.14.19).

Check **Preferences** > **Profiles** > **Window** > **Custom window title** and enter something like:

```
\(currentTab.currentSession.path) \(currentTab.currentSession.columns)x\(currentTab.currentSession.rows)
```